# How many images are generated when ImageDataGenerator is used, and when data augmentation is included as a part of the model?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-classification, image-preprocessing, data-augmentation

Is there any way to know the number of images generated by the **ImageDataGenerator** class and loading data using **flow_from_directory** method? I searched everywhere for the same but couldn't find anything useful.

Also, if I use **image_dataset_from_directory** fuction, I have to include **data augmentation layers as a part of the model.** In that case, how many images are generated?

My **ImageDataGenerator** code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=15,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')
```

My code with **data augmentation as a part of the model**:

```
data_aug = Sequential([
                         layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
                         layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
                         layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2,0.2),
                         layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.06)
])



# in the model:

input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
x = data_aug(input_layer)
```

Answer (score 2):

*In one epoch* - It's the number of images in your *Directory or the DataFrame*

 In case of a custom Generator. It will be `batch_size * steps_per_epoch`

You may check this with any of these approaches -

- Check the shape of prediction on train `model.predict(traindata).shape`
- Save the images into a dir by using `save_to_dir='/content/train_data'`
- Write a `callback` for batch_end
- Get the `steps_per_epoch` in the training print statement i.e.

  ***125/125** [==============================] - 50s 392ms/step - loss: 0.6637 - accuracy: 0.6000*

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is this the same when **"image_dataset_from_directory"** is used?